# Arms motion with coordinate argument with NAO?

Tags: python, motion, nao-robot

I am beginner with NAO programming and I am now working on a project involving arms motion.

I must program a game in which NAO would first stand and point out one among three squares with different colors which would be displayed on the ground.

I think that I can "simply" make Nao move its arm so he would point towards one of three different pre-defined coordinates.

However, animation mode and motion widget do not seem usable for movements with parameters, like one out of the three coordinates.

How do I perform such a move ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you look at the ALMotion.setPositions type of method ?

There are methods working in cartesian space. It means that you just positionnate some end effector (eg the hand) to be at a specific positions compared to the origin of the chest (for instance).
You can see that as a vector pointing to a direction...

The solver used for that could be enhanced, but it's a nice way to achieve what you need to do.

More info there:

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/motion/control-cartesian-api.html#ALMotionProxy::setPositions__AL::ALValueCR.AL::ALValueCR.AL::ALValueCR.floatCR.AL::ALValueCR

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the pointAt method which takes in parameters the position that you would like to point. If the position of your three objects are known in advance, that would do the job. You can find more here:

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/trackers/altracker-api.html#ALTrackerProxy::pointAt__ssCR.std::vector:float:CR.iCR.floatCR